# RSpec & Devise authentication don't works

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, devise, bdd

I having very weird problem with RSpec and Devise

```
  describe 'GET edit:/id' do 
    before do 
      @job = FactoryGirl.create(:job)
      get(:edit, id: @job.id)
    end

    context 'as not authorized' do
      before { logout(:user) }
      it 'redirects to login page' do
        expect(response).to redirect_to new_user_session_path
      end
    end

    #it '' do end << works if i uncomment this line

     context 'as authorized' do
      before { login_as(user) }
      it 'renders edit tempalte' do
        expect(response).to render_template :edit
       # Here I get response.status 302. It must be 200, controller thinks that user is not authorized.
       # But if add empty 'it' keyword, everything works fine
      end
    end
  end
```

Controller's before filter

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why everything works fine if add empty 'it' keyword.

But, I know why **context 'as authorized'** doesn't work fine.
I tried it and the code works fine.

#### Spec file. I change 2 lines. Please look at comments.

```
# spec/controllers/jobs_controller.rb
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe JobsController, :type => :controller do
  describe 'GET edit:/id' do
    context 'as not authorized' do
      before do
        @job = FactoryGirl.create(:job)
        get(:edit, id: @job.id)
      end
      it 'redirects to login page' do
        expect(response).to redirect_to new_user_session_path
      end
    end

    context 'as authorized' do
      before do
        user = FactoryGirl.create(:user) # add here
        sign_in(user)  # change
        @job = FactoryGirl.create(:job)
        get(:edit, id: @job.id)
      end

      it 'renders edit tempalte' do
        expect(response).to render_template :edit
      end
    end
  end
end
```

#### Add Devise's test helpers to `rails_helper.rb`.

```
# spec/rails_helper.rb
# Add this line to provide Devise's test helpers
# Ref: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#test-helpers
config.include Devise::TestHelpers, type: :controller
```

#### Factory file.

```
# spec/factories/users.rb
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    email 'test@email.com'
    password 'password'
  end
end
```

#### Run and success!!

```
rspec spec/controllers/jobs_controller_spec.rb
..

Finished in 0.09395 seconds (files took 2.31 seconds to load)
2 examples, 0 failures
```

Comment: Thank you for response but i dot understand what you mean can you please provide code?

Comment: I mean that before you `login_as(user)` (No 2.), you request `get(:edit, id: @job.id)` (No 1).  So, devise return **unauthorized** with status code **302**.

Comment: I ve updated lik this https://gist.github.com/lekishvili/53cd2329df39e61762c3 but having same problem

Comment: Thanks for sharing your code. I tried it and edited the answer. Please look them.